# for loop going into the negative when it is supposed to stop at 0 in c

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int i = 0;
int index = 0;
void temp = malloc(sizeof(double));
struct Array array;
struct Performance performance;

for (i = 20; i >= index; i--) {
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    readItem(performance, array, i, temp);
    writeItem(performance, array, i+1, temp);
}
```

I'm having a problem in c where I am wanting to have a for loop run from 20 to 0 but as soon as it hit zero it goes into the negative, I checked my value of i at the beginning of the for loop but still goes past zero, my readItem function then stops the for loop but I am wondering how to solve this problem. (The function for readItem and writeItem do not affect the integer "i" in anyway)

```
final output: i:-1
```

Sorry in advance if my post is poorly formatted this is my first time posting and any advice on how to post better would be appreciated.

Comment: `void=malloc()` ??  What is that supposed to do?

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow what your problem _really_ is based on what you described here. But generally you should expect the _final_ value of `i` to be -1 after the loop has iterated to completion. This is due to your condition that `i >= 0`, meaning that the loop will iterate for the case where `i=0` followed by a final decrement of i to -1 which breaks the next iteration.

A fundamental take-away here is that the `i--` part will execute _after_ the loop has iterated. [Try it online](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ-_z8zLw).

Comment: Your loop terminates when `i` is no longer `>= 0`. So it must be negative (actually -1).

Comment: Thank you all for you help your comments solved my problem even though I wasn't fully clear in my question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly :

```
int i=0;
int index=0;
for(i = 20; i >= index; i--)
{
  printf("i: %d\n", i);
}
printf("final output: i: %d\n", i);
```

That is normal. You initialize `i = 20`, then each loop you do `i--`, which means that it will decrement (20, 19, 18...), each time checking if the exit condition is met (20>=0, 19>=0, ... 0>=0). When you hit the final loop, `i` will decrement to `-1`, the condition `-1>=0` will be false, and the loop will stop.

If you print `i` after the loop, its value will be `-1` because that was the exit condition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you confusing python for loops with C for loops, maybe?  At any rate, i will be -1 when it terminates the loop.

If this is basically what you did:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i;
    int index;
    index=0;




    for(i=20; i>=index; i--){
        printf("i: %d\n",i);
     }
    printf("i: %d\n",i); // i will be -1 because of the previous i--
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ ./main.exe
i: 20
i: 19
i: 18
i: 17
i: 16
i: 15
i: 14
i: 13
i: 12
i: 11
i: 10
i: 9
i: 8
i: 7
i: 6
i: 5
i: 4
i: 3
i: 2
i: 1
i: 0
i: -1
```